# its is possible to use lighting design components(Salesforce) in normal Reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am new to the ReactJs. I already tried some UI library like Material UI and Grommet, Now i  wanted to know its is possible to use lighting design components(Salesforce) in normal Reactjs application?

In simple words possible to use lighting design components(Salesforce) for non-Salesforce applictions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its possible. There is an npm package for that. You can reference it from here:

https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/

Comment: but in my project i just wanted to use those components (No relation with salesforce cloud or any other connection with salesforce)